# iPhone downgrade - is it frozen?

Tags: iphone, ios, performance, downgrade

I have iPhone 6s. I had iOS 14.2. i need to go back to version 14.1. I download this [version](https://ipsw.me/download/iPhone8,1/18A8395) and
run downgrade from my MAC. Now I have this on my iPhone:

[image]

This is the label in my MAC:

[image]

Translate:

```
Restore iPhone
Mac computer is currently restoring software to iphone
```

Sometimes I see the apple logo, but it quickly changes to this drawing. this has been going on for about 1.5 hours. this is normal? or is the installation process frozen? any advice - I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Can you elaborate on how did you proceed with downgrading?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it hung. I restarted this and I was able to downgrade successfully. I used these materials:

[how-to-downgrade-ios](https://www.imore.com/how-to-downgrade-ios)

[downgrade-ios-3664217](https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/downgrade-ios-3664217/)

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong, 14.1 is still signed for a short time. When that window closes, the rest here will be true...

---

You have to break a bunch of preconditions to jailbreak a device and load older versions in iOS since they are designed to be updated only and never regress. The short answer is without you listing exactly what you have done, letting the current version be reinstalled is the pragmatic solution to a working phone that isn’t broken.

The version you downloaded may be tampered with and it certainly isn’t signed by Apple so you’re in essence asking how to set up your own trust chain to run unsigned code.

The problems you experience are normal, expected when you attempt to downgrade with perfectly working hardware.

Comment: iOS 14.1 is still being signed as of today (November 11), downgrading should be perfectly easy and possible. https://ipsw.me/iPhone8,1

Comment: Cool, I should have checked. I’ll be wrong for a week or so and shocked if it’s signed into December. That would be a fascinating development if it happens @Wowfunhappy thanks so much for the correction.